# Microsoft Azure AD B2C - email_ver_but_resend id - twice in the same page

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Hello I have an issue with Azure AD B2C. Basically my purpose is to use twice, in the same html page
the button with the same ID email_ver_but_resend like:

```
<button id="email_ver_but_resend" class="sendButton" type="button" aria-label="Send new code" aria-hidden="false"><span>Resend_1</span></button>

<button id="email_ver_but_resend" class="sendButton" type="button" aria-label="Send new code" aria-hidden="false"><span>Resend_2</span></button>
```

but this solution is not allowed because the id should be unique; indeed doesn't work.
I thought that instead of using the id **email_ver_but_resend** maybe there is some class I can use.

Any suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: May I know why you require 2 buttons with the same ID? What is the use case you want to achieve?

Comment: Because my understanding is the action related to the "Send Verification Code" button/link is injected by Azure AD B2C, and in order to achieve that you should use 
the id 'email_ver_but_resend'. In my case I need associate that action to 2 different buttons in the same page (one below the form and another one in case an error is raised). I'm beginner  with this B2C, I've never used it before. I started to use it 2 weeks ago. Could you give me some advices?

Comment: I will suggest to play around with User Flow of Azure AD B2C, that will give you more ideas how B2C works and how the SignUp Flow happen. If you want to use Custom Policy (Identity Experience Framework) try this link: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack. If need any hep you can checkout the documentations:  https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/.  

Hope this will hep you.

Comment: We have Custom policy as well.  I need just a confirm. Is it possible implement my situation using B2C or not?

Comment: For "Send Verification Code" B2C use email_ver_but_send and to send a new code it use email_ver_but_resend. Whether you are trying to implement custom verification flow for Email.

Comment: OK many thanks. I found a solution defining onClick event of the second button the click action of the first button.